Firewall rule to allow SMB samba share between VLANs [openwrt]
Router     : OpenWrt firmware 23.05
Main LAN   : 192.168.1.*
SMB server : 192.168.1.2
Guest VLAN : 192.168.20.*

I have vlan.20 for Guest (internet access only) separated from my local network. My samba server @ 192.168.1.2. Could anyone please help me with what traffic rule do I need to allow Guest to browse my samba share server?
Firewall zone setup

The traffic rule I came up with, but no success


I believe with hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.2/255.255.0.0 should cover all my VLANs. To be honest I have very little knowledge about samba & routing. @JaromandaX do you have any insight about static routes to achieve this kind of connection?

I believe with hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.2/255.255.0.0 should cover all my VLANs - are your windows machines on 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0 subnet? What's the point of VLAN's if they are all in the same subnet!

That is 1 line in the smb.conf setting file of my samba server only. My local network (including samba server) on 192.168.1.0/24. For example a friend visit me, connect to the Guest wifi and they will be on 192.168.20.0/24. The purpose of VLANs is none of the guests can access my local network. Now I want my friend to browse my media server to play music & movies too.

A bit more clear, I have a Windows PC @ 192.168.1.5. This windows machine can access 192.168.1.2 linux samba server just fine. A friend visit with his laptop, he connect to the Guest wifi and will be assigned 192.168.20.100. The question is IDK how to config the samba server or setup a traffic rule on the router (192.168.1.1) so that my friend's 192.168.20.100 laptop able to connect to the samba share

So what you want to say is I need to config the linux samba server so it can listen on 192.168.20.0/24 right. The problem is I don't know how to do that. Can you look at this settings section of the server to point out what do I need to change/add?bind interfaces only = yes interfaces = lo br0 192.168.1.2/255.255.255.0 hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.2/255.255.255.0 hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0. One more thing, does my firewall zones setup above permit such kind of listening?

I think I understand a little bit more. But allow me to describe my situation. My samba server is actually an old wireless router (linux based firmware) with usb 3.0 port, static LAN IP 192.168.1.2, DHCP disabled. I'm using it as an unmanaged gigabit switch + dumb wireless Access Point + smb share on untagged 192.168.1.0/24 subnet, because its firmware not capable of Vlan tagging. The only hope for me (in my imagination) is through some routing/forwarding magic with the new main OpenWrt router to achieve my goal, so is this even possible?

Guest VLAN was created in the new main OpenWrt router. The old one with samba server running (now considered as one generic device) is plugged into 1 untagged ethenet port (dedicated to 192.168.1.0/24 Vlan) of the main router
